# App Store Connect wouldn't show new apps. What should I do?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

As said in title, since yesterday App Store Connect wouldn't show new app icons on "My apps" screen. Old apps icons are shown correctly, but if I create a new app and then go to "My apps" screen there won't be any icon for it, as if I didn't create it.

There was a short outage of App Store Connect API in the morning, but it looks like all systems are stable now.

Comment: The app icon doesn't show up until your first version is reviewed and approved

Comment: I'm not talking about the app icon, I'm talking about the app itself. I know that app icon doesn't show up until the first version is approved. But this time, the app simply does not appear in apps list. As if I didn't create it.

Comment: Also Xcode keeps saying that there's no app with such SKU on App Store, although it's definitely registered. When I'm trying to upload the build, it says that there's already another build with such SKU on App Store

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it's on their side ‍♂️

Comment: @room_it it’s fixed, now I can see the apps 

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed fixed. Looks like the problem was on their side